# How do I merge and sort two json lists using key value

Tags: python, json

I can get a JSON list of groups and devices from an API, but the key values don't allow me to do a merge without manipulating the returned lists. Unfortunately, the group info and devices info have to be retrieved using separate http requests.

The code for getting the group info looks like this:

```
    #Python Code
    import requests
    import simplejson as json
    import datetime
    import pprintpp 

    print datetime.datetime.now().time()

    url = 'https://www.somecompany.com/api/v2/groups/?fields=id,name'
    s = requests.Session()

    ## Ver2 API Authenticaion ##
    headers = {
        'X-ABC-API-ID': 'nnnn-nnnn-nnnn-nnnn-nnnn',
        'X-ABC-API-KEY': 'nnnnnnnn',
        'X-DE-API-ID': 'nnnnnnnn',
        'X-DE-API-KEY': 'nnnnnnnn'
    }
    r = json.loads(s.get((url), headers=headers).text)

    print "Working...Groups extracted"
    groups = r["data"]
    print "*** Ver2 API Groups Information ***"
    pprintpp.pprint (groups)
```

The printed output of groups looks like this:

```
    #Groups
    [
        {u'id': u'0001', u'name': u'GroupA'},
        {u'id': u'0002', u'name': u'GroupB'},
    ]
```

The code for getting the devices info looks like this:

```
    url = 'https://www.somecompany.com/api/v2/devicess/?limit=500&fields=description,group,id,name'
    r = json.loads(s.get((url), headers=headers).text)

    print "Working...Devices extracted"
    devices = r["data"]
    print "*** Ver2 API Devices Information ***"
    pprintpp.pprint (devices)
```

The devices output looks like this:

```
    #Devices
    [
        {
            u'description': u'GroupB 100 (City State)',
            u'group': u'https://www.somecompany.com/api/v2/groups/0002/',
            u'id': u'90001',
            u'name': u'ABC550-3e9',
        },
        {
            u'description': u'GroupA 101 (City State)',
            u'group': u'https://www.somecompany.com/api/v2/groups/0001/',
            u'id': u'90002',
            u'name': u'ABC500-3e8',
        }
    ]
```

What I would like to do is to be able to merge and sort the two JSON lists into an output that looks like this:

```
    #Desired Output
    #Seperated List of GroupA & GroupB Devices
    [
        {u'id': u'0001', u'name': u'GroupA'},

           {
              u'description': u'GroupA 101 (City State)',
              u'group': u'https://www.somecompany.com/api/v2/groups/0001/',
              u'id': u'90002',
              u'name': u'ABC500-3e8',
           },

        {u'id': u'0002', u'name': u'GroupB'},

           {
              u'description': u'GroupB 100 (City State)',
              u'group': u'https://www.somecompany.com/api/v2/groups/0002/',
              u'id': u'90001',
              u'name': u'ABC550-3e9',
           }
    ]
```

A couple of problems I am having is that the key names for groups and devices output are not unique. The key named 'id' in groups is actually the same value as the last 4 digits of the key named 'group' in devices, and is the value I wish to use for the sort. Also, 'id' and 'name' in groups is different than 'id' and 'name' in devices. My extremely limited skill with Python is making this quite the challenge. Any help with pointing me in the correct direction for a solution will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: merge -> `res = groups + devices`. sort -> `res = sorted(res, key=itemgetter(u'id'))`

Comment: So you want to put together the json objects from list 1 and list 2 such that list 1's 'name' somehow matches list 2's 'description'?

Comment: how do you identify which device belongs to which group?

Comment: List 1 'id' key is the same as the last 4 digits of list 2 'group' key. This is what I need to use for the sort.

Answer (score 0):

This program produces your desired output:

```
import pprintpp
groups = [
        {u'id': u'0001', u'name': u'GroupA'},
        {u'id': u'0002', u'name': u'GroupB'},
    ]

devices = [
        {
            u'description': u'GroupB 100 (City State)',
            u'group': u'https://www.somecompany.com/api/v2/groups/0002/',
            u'id': u'90001',
            u'name': u'ABC550-3e9',
        },
        {
            u'description': u'GroupA 101 (City State)',
            u'group': u'https://www.somecompany.com/api/v2/groups/0001/',
            u'id': u'90002',
            u'name': u'ABC500-3e8',
        }
    ]

desired = sorted(
    groups + devices,
    key = lambda x: x.get('group', x.get('id')+'/')[-5:-1])

pprintpp.pprint(desired)
```

Or, if that `lambda` does not seem self-documenting:

```
def key(x):
    '''Sort on either the last few digits of x['group'], if that exists,
       or the entirety of x['id'], if x['group'] does not exist.
    '''
    if 'group' in x:
        return x['group'][-5:-1]
    return x['id']
desired = sorted(groups + devices, key=key)
```

Comment: I get an undefined variable: sorted error when I use the examples above. If I define sorted as and int or str, I get int error and str error respectively.

Comment: I find that difficult to believe. Did you copy-paste precisely what I supplied? Here is an example of it working: http://ideone.com/tovGBl

Comment: I am using the JSON returned from:                                                                   r = json.loads(s.get((url), headers=headers).text)                               groups = r["data"] for "groups" and the same method for "devices" Do I need to insert the raw JSON into your code?

Comment: Also, my version of Python is 2.7.10

Comment: The error message is from my IDE. Aptana Studio 3. It reads "Undefined variable: sorted"

Comment: I have traced the "Undefined variable" issue back to my IDE. Thanks for your reply to my question.